# connecting an event to function in javascript for pdf

Tags: javascript

im trying to write something in javascript to extend my adobe reader functionlaty.

i have written a function and added it to my menu item and its working fine.
im looking for a way to connecy function to specific events that happen in the file
e.g.
run the function when i click anywhere in the document.

i saw on the documention that an event object is automatically created with specifc properties.
but i dont know how to use that event in the moment it is created, and how to make it to start a function.

thx for the help.

Comment: What about http://bit.ly/1qvL5eY?

Comment: still cant find my answer there

Comment: Sorry, I think misunderstood your question, my fault. Sorry. I found [this](http://www.planetpdf.com/developer/article.asp?ContentID=working_with_events_in_acrobat&gid=6823&mh) one and [this (in German)](http://acronaut.de/forum10/4025.html) where something similar was discussed using context3D. Sorry again for being rude to you, good luck solving your problem.

Comment: i also found this one, which explains about a few common events. there is also a full event documantion in the adobe guid. but i cant find any code example for using those events. lets say i click on the file or move page, it creates an event. but how do i use that to trigger a function?

Comment: also tried using something like                            this.onclick = function();                                           when this is pointing to the doc object. but it doesnt work, it calls the function once when the pdf is opened.

Comment: Mhh... I read some parts of the documentation and it seems that you only can bind events to buttons and similar elements.

Comment: any way of adding a listener, somthing like: this.addEventListener("click",function_name);