# bind function to action in pdf javascript

Tags: javascript

i wrote a function in javascript for pdf and added it as a button to my menu

the function adds a annotation to the pdf, but i want to be able to determine where the annotation will be placed. i want to use the mouse for that.

i cant find a way for connectiong a mouse click to the function i wrote,
according to what i saw in the java api documantion there is no way to bind a click event to the function.

i tried doing something which is pure java script like this.addEventListener with no success
also tried adding to my code some js libraries like KeyboardJS but also no success.

id rather have a way to bind my function to a mouse click, but a way to bind it to a specific key could also be very useful.

thank you

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [your previous question?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701585/connecting-an-event-to-function-in-javascript-for-pdf)? Maybe you could post some code you've tried, or link to the relevant documentation?

Comment: i tried using 
this.addEventListener("click",function(){
app.alert("test");
}
also tried "onclick" and "Mouse Up" instead of click
i found some libraries that creates keys and mouse events listener like "mousestrap" , KeyboardJS . i didnt find any include in javascript so i copied the entire text into my code but it didnt work. looks like its intended to be used in a browser. this is the documnation im using http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat10_SDK_HTMLHelp&file=JS_Dev_Overview.71.1.html

Comment: solved by creating a transpernet field over the entire text and connecting the function to a click event on the field using this code:

for (var i = 0; i < myDoc.numPages; i++) {
  // create a rectengle on the entire page
  var Rect = this.getPageBox( {nPage: i} );

  // Now construct an invisible button 
  var f = this.addField("Give comment", "button", i, Rect );
  f.setAction("MouseUp","function_name");
  f.fillColor = color.transparent;